# Does the web version of MS Office 365 work on Ubuntu?

Tags: office365

In theory, if I can run it in FireFox, there should be no problem.  Of course the devil is in the details. Has anyone tried this?

Comment: ehm. Why don't you tell us? We don't have a license ;-) It is webbased so the OS should not matter. If Microsoft is so childish to check for the user-agent you can spoof that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have an Office 365 license for work, and it does indeed work from a Linux machine.  (I didn't get the license by choice >.>)

The only difference is that if it's an Office for Business you have to go through your workplace's Sharepoint namespace rather than the office.com online versions; however it will still function as normal.

Answer (score 4):

Office 365 runs on my Ubuntu 18.04 via Firefox. Have 365 at work and can send & receive messages at home. Can also load & run Word & Excel at home. Not 100% functional but is doable. If you do not have access to 365, you would need to register with 365 and pay a fee to use it. It should still work with Linux & Firefox.

Comment: BTW Dropbox has Word, Excel, and Powerpoint for free online, for personal accounts. FAQ: [Microsoft Office for Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/microsoft-office-faq#web)

Comment: Interesting. TY for Info.

Answer (score 0):

I use office 365 with crossover. Web version works fine, but there are many features that are only part of the desktop app. To get the desktop apps working I did the following:

1) Get the 64 bit installer for office 365. I did this by downloading it from my office 365 online account (I have a university account). This requires spoofing your user agent string otherwise the install button doesn't show up online. I used a firefox extension to do this, and set it to use win7 64 bit user agent string. Once you've downloaded the installer,you can turn off or uninstall the user agent extension.

2) Install office 365 via crossover with the 64 bit installer.

I have used wine, playonlinux, etc in the past. But this was the only way I got office 365 working. It was pretty painless in comparison to the awful experience I have had otherwise in the past.